# why iron and steel not arcing?

Tags: mechanical

I'm messing around with a 3-6 V to 20-40kv converter

My question is when I try steel, aluminum, or iron it doesn't send electric through air and arc, like this picture

[image]

But when i use copper to make them arc, it works fine, like this picture

[image: enter image description]

I also checked some youtube videos they use steel and iron and they arc fine, like this video he uses an iron screw it arcs

https://youtu.be/6dnfz_O9pxQ

Why it doesnt arc with iron and steel? But arc with copper?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? I'm sure i've seen an identical question, but can't now find it.

Comment: Check the resistance of the wires...

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: @Colin__s He is quick :) I'll be deleting my comments then Cheers.

Comment: Hmm, you asked basically the same question yesterday. Which was closed. This looks like an **exact copy** of that question! What are you hoping to achieve with that?

Comment: what exactly is the point of including the second picture?

Comment: The last topic was dead as i didnt explained my question very good, so i deleted and posted a fresh topic but it looks like the old one hasnt been deleted

Answer (score 5):

If you have kV the material of the wires (provided it is metal) is not important.

What is important is the spacing of the gap and how pointy the ends are. If they are very pointy the electric field gradient is higher and it is easier to break down (ionize) the air and start an arc.

Try reducing the gap and/or making the ends sharper.

Once the arc starts the nature of the arc may be different because some of the metal will be vaporized, but I suspect unless the tips are very sharp you don't have enough power to vaporize much metal.

Comment: Corona discharge wires in photocopiers and laser printers were gold plated at times to increase the surface conductivity (and minimise ozone induced corrosion) and maintain predictable behaviour.  Copper conductivity might give a tiny bit more field strength than steel but geometry (spacing and radius) are more likely to make a real difference.